# I want to copy data of a specific columns (by using column headers) from one workbook to another workbook using VBA Macro

Tags: excel

I am new to VBA Macros. I just know how to copy cells/columns from one worksheet to another sheet and one workbook to another workbook.

I don't know how to copy data "using column headers" (need total column values) from one workbook to another workbook.

Could someone please help me in this regard.

Excel looks like below and I want to copy data by using headers "Job Name & Job Status") to another workbook

```
Joboutput details
Location
Date

Job Name  Job Number  Job Status
aaa
bbb
```